# Selecting all excel files with "504" in the title made/modified on today's date

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'd like to be able to attach all my excel (xlsm) files that have "504" in the title that were made on today's date to an Outlook email. I can have 1 or 10+ files with "504" in the title made in one day.

Below you can see my current code. This code allows me to attach 1 excel file but it also most be the most recently modified (created).

```
Sub Attach()
Dim folder As String
Dim file As String
Dim mail_body As String
Dim signature As String
Dim OApp As Object
Dim OMail As Object

Sheet1.Visible = False
Sheet2.Visible = False
Sheet3.Visible = False
Sheet4.Visible = False
Sheet5.Visible = False

folder = "C:Folder\504"
file = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir /b /o-d """ & folder & """*.xlsm").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)(0)
mail_body = "Hello," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attached is the 504 for " & Sheet4.Range("D4") & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Thank you,"


Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OMail
    .display
    End With
        signature = OMail.body



With OMail
    .To = "anybody@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "504 " & Sheet4.Range("D3")
    .body = mail_body & vbNewLine & signature
    .Attachments.Add folder & file
    .display
End With


MsgBox ("Please confirm email and click SEND. Once the payoff has bee sent 
the process is now complete! Thank you!")

End Sub
```

Any help would be great!!

Comment: Use `Dir()` to loop over the matching files, and attach the ones matching the date criteria.

Comment: ...or loop over your existing array from Split(), and use `FileDateTime()` to check its age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Dir` and `FileDateTime`

(With email portion commented out for my testing, but shows where to put this code)

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Patt As String
    Dim fl As String
    Dim FileDate As Date
    Dim TodayDate As Date

    Path = "C:\Folder\"
    Patt = "504*.xlsm"
    TodayDate = Int(Now())

' your other code ...

'    With OMail
'        .To = "anybody@gmail.com"
'        .Subject = "504 " & Sheet4.Range("D3")
'        .body = mail_body & vbNewLine & Signature
        fl = Dir(Path & Patt)
        Do While fl <> vbNullString
            FileDate = Int(FileDateTime(fl))
            If FileDate = TodayDate Then
                '.Attachments.Add Path & fl
            End If
            fl = Dir()
        Loop
'        .display
'    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So far this one works like a charm! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()
    Const folder As String = "C:\Folder\"
    Dim arr, f
    arr = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir /b /o-d """ & _
                             folder & "504*.xlsm""").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)

    For Each f In arr
        If Len(f) > 0 Then
            'attach if less than 24hrs old
            If (Now - FileDateTime(folder & f)) < 1 Then
                Debug.Print "Attaching", f
                'attach the file...
            End If
        End If
    Next f
End Sub
```